# Angular Binding problem with Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router, angular-reactive-forms

Below is the HTML Component

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
<mat-card fxFlex="30">
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-title>
            <h2>Employee Details Form</h2>
        </mat-card-title>
        <form class="login-form"  [formGroup]="empForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div fxLayout="column">
                <p>
                    <mat-form-field class="item">
                        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="First Name" value={{firstName}} formControlName="fname"> 
                    </mat-form-field>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <mat-form-field class="item">
                        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value={{lastName}} formControlName="lname">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <mat-form-field class="item">
                        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Email ID" value={{emailId}} formControlName="email">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </p>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">
                    <mat-icon>mic</mat-icon>
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

I need to bind form fields which I have already taken from angular http get method.

ts component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeeService } from '../service/employee/employee.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-detail',
  templateUrl: './employee-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-detail.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  public id: number;
  public empForm: FormGroup;
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;
  public emailId: string;

  constructor(private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute, private employeeService: EmployeeService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.empForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fname: [''],
      lname: [''],
      email: ['']
    });

    this.id = this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(this.id).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.firstName = response.firstName;
        this.lastName = response.lastName;
        this.emailId = response.emailId;
      });    
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("From EMP")
    console.log(this.empForm.value);
  }
}
```

When I print the values in console I get empty form values but when I edit the form fields and submit I get proper values. My concern is I should be getting values without even updating the form fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `value` attribute to set the value. Instead you can set the values directly to your form. Check this:

```
this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(this.id).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.firstName = response.firstName;
        this.lastName = response.lastName;
        this.emailId = response.emailId;

        this.empForm.patchValue({
           fname: this.firstName,
           lname: this.lastName,
           email: this.emailId
        });
});
```

Like this you will get two-way binding with reactive form.
And remove `value` attribute from input tag.

Comment: Thanks Tushar, have resolved this problem after applying your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <mat-card fxFlex="30">
        <mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-title>
                <h2>Employee Details Form</h2>
            </mat-card-title>
            <form class="login-form"  [formGroup]="empForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div fxLayout="column">
                    <p>
                        <mat-form-field class="item">
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="fname"> 
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <mat-form-field class="item">
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Last Name"  formControlName="lname">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <mat-form-field class="item">
                            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Email ID" formControlName="email">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </p>
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">
                        <mat-icon>mic</mat-icon>
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

and for your .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeeService } from '../service/employee/employee.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-detail',
  templateUrl: './employee-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-detail.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  id: number;
  empForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute, private employeeService: EmployeeService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.empForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fname: [''],
      lname: [''],
      email: ['']
    });

    this.id = this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(this.id).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.empForm.setValue(response);
      });    
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("From EMP")
    console.log(this.empForm.value);
  }
}
```

Do your best to ensure that the object that gets returned from your api matches all of the properties and the casing inside of your declared empForm FormGroup.

This may additionally come in handy:
https://www.positronx.io/angular-8-reactive-forms-validation-with-angular-material-8/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but this doesn't still working I have applied below given fix and its working. Also 2 way binding is also possible for the same.